# udevadm trigger runs only one rule

Tags: udev, sleep

I have 1294:1320 RISO KAGAKU device on F17. The problem is after sleep/resume hid reclaims this device back and its udev rule is ignored. If I unplug and plug in the device it is OK until next sleep/resume. So, I tried to use udevadm trigger

```
udevadm trigger  --attr-match=idVendor=1294 --subsystem-match=usb --attr-match=idProduct=1320 --action=add
```

But unfortunately it doesn't trigger proper rule. HAL rule is triggered instead. Which is exactly what I don't want to happen. I tried to add to the HAL rule

```
ATTRS{idVendor}!="1294", ATTRS{idProduct}!="1320"
```

but it doesn't help even after rule reload.

Any ideas how to deal with resume?

Comment: The best way I have found is to provide `/etc/pm/sleep.d/99-usbled.sh` with heuristic usb device detection script to rebind the device.